# How do I navigate in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, react-router, frontend

It's my first time using react native and I want to move to another screen (slide2), I have had errors and I am kind of stuck, this is how far I have gone.

Please also explaining a bit will be very much appreciated, thank you

**slideOne page code**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SlideTwo from './SlideTwo';
import React from 'react';


const SlideOne: () => React$Node = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <View style={styles.imageWrap}></View>

          <TextInput
            placeholder="What should we refer to you as?"
            placeholderTextColor="#03444F60"
            style={styles.textInput}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.label}>
          <Text style={styles.labelText}>First Name</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.textWrap}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Back</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Next</Text>
        </View>
        <Button
          title="Go to screen two"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SlideTwo')}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFC7B9',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

 backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    borderRadius: 13,
  },
```

this is my index.js where the routing is

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
    import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import SlideOne from './SlideOne';
    import SlideTwo from './SlideTwo';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => SlideOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by creating a stack navigator(I would create a file only for navigation, it can get very complex and long):

```
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';    
import SlideOne from './SlideOne';
import SlideTwo from './SlideTwo';

// NAVIGATION
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    SlideOne: SlideOne,
    SlideTwo: SlideTwo,
})

export default createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

Now you just import this file into your App.js, like:

```
import Navigator from './navigation/Navigator'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
             <Navigator />
             {//... your code here}
        </React.Fragment>
    (
}
```

Now you can call any navigation inside your code with this.props.navigation.navigate